# How to delete multiple rows from table using Angular.js?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to delete multi rows from table using checkbox with Angular and php , 
but i'm not able to get that to work and my knowledge with Angular stoped here !

this is my table :

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x: unset;">           
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteBulk()" >Delete</button>

    <table datatable="ng" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>                
                <th ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="master" > select</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>first name</th>
                <th>last name</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>action</th>
                <th>action</th>
                <th>action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" ng-repeat="name in namesData "     >
                <td name="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="arrExample"
                         ng-model="arrInput" ng-true-value="{{name.id}}"
                         ng-checked="master"
                         ng-click='pushInArray(name.id)'>
                </td>
                <td>{{name.date}}</td>
                <td>{{name.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{name.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{name.age}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="fetchSingleData(name.id)" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">edit</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="deleteData(name.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">delete</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="single_move(name.id)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">send</button></td>            
            </tr>
        </tbody>            
    </table>
```

and this is my Angular code :

```
$scope.exampleArray = [];
$scope.pushInArray = function(id) {
     // get the input value
     var inputVal = id;
     var array = $scope.exampleArray.push(inputVal);
     $scope.deleteBulk = function(){
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")){
             $http({
                 method:"POST",
                 url:"insert.php",
                 data:{'id':$scope.exampleArray, 'action' : 'deleteBulk'}
             }).success(function(data){
                $scope.success = true;
                $scope.error = false;
                $scope.successMessage = data.message;
                $scope.fetchData();
             });
        }
    };   
};
```

and this is my php code inside insert.php

```
if($form_data->action == "deleteBulk")
{
    $query = "
     DELETE FROM orders WHERE id='".$form_data->id."'
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
        $output['message'] = 'done!';
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong please ?
thank you

Comment: You need to convert example array into comma (,) separated string then get it into PHP.

Comment: @SantoshAnand can you explain that please ?

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting one row each time with a unique id. So code base is correct.

To delete multiple rows, use the checkbox in each row and user will select multiple rows to delete and then delete rows by multiple ids.

You will also need to update SQL query to delete multiple rows at a time.

Something like below

```
DELETE FROM orders WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 10);
```

Comment: i'm already using the checkbox in each row , but i don't know why i'm able to delete only one row each time :/

Comment: Yes. because you are probaly sending one id to the back end. And sql query is also to delete one row.
You will need to update both API and SQL query.

Send ids like array and apply it to the query.